# Создание папки при регистрации по id

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы при регистрации создавалась папка по id юзера, и в этой папке был его профайл аватарки фото и такого типа? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: вероятно, нужен mkdir, туда передавать id (откуда оно там берется).

Comment: Я думаю что ничего создавать не нужно, а нужно почитать про ЧПУ, роуты

Comment: Я думаю удобнее хранить информацию о пользователе в его папке, альбомы его фотографии.Чем всех юзеров в одной папке, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Хмм... не плохо,а как сделать так что бы вместе с каталогом создавалось еще и его содержимое... файлы в нем такие как *.php, .hcacces, *.html ? например то нужное содержимое хранится в основной папки и каждый раз копи-пастнеться при регистрации **но уже с заданными параметрами из регистрации** ? Правильно сформулированный мною вопрос приведен на нижней сылке. http://hashcode.ru/questions/384940/mysql-php-создание-папки-при-регистрации-по-id-с-содержанием-файлов

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function registerUser(){
    //Регистрируем юзера и получаем его ID
    return $lastInsertId;
}

$uid = registerUser();        
mkdir("/path/to/site/users/".$uid."/", 0700); //права нужные поставить
```

При этом не забыть об обработке ошибок и о том, что может случиться так, что не получиться создать папку - тогда пользователя предупредить и повторить регистрацию.

Comment: @aldem67 спасибо большое вам.