# Создание папки при регистрации по id с содержанием файлов

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добра!

Основопологаясь на тему [Создание папки при регистрации по id](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/284974/php-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-id)
, после мною его успешной реализации возник ниже описанный вопрос.

Как сделать так, чтобы вместе с каталогом создавалось еще его содержимое... файлы в нем, такие как *.php, .hcacces, *.html с глобальным внутренним содержимым, которое задавалось при регистрации?
...

(пример для непонятых -1)

-при регистрации совместно созданием папки, в папку нового пользователя сохраняются файлы ([например] из основного источника "Основного каталога" такие как *.php с содержанием информации, которая была введена в форме при регистрации пользователя.

(пример для непонятых -2a Пошагово)

1)Действие:Создал пользователя ivan

2|Функции скрипта при регистрации

перваяФ-создалась папка ../user/ivan последоватеьно в каталоге../ivan создался файл ../ivan/index.php содержащие в себе свойство файла ../user/default/default1.php, но уже с теми **параметрами**, что были введены при регистрации, такие как =-->
(Параметры выделенны **)

```
<?php
if($_SESSION["login"] == *ivan*) {
?>
      <form action="http://site.ru/user/*ivan*/save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Функция вторая - таким же способом в той же папке того же пользователя ../user/ivan из основного каталога (с файлом) ../user/default/default2.php создаётся файл 
../user/ivan/save.php с *параметрами* содержимого того же, что задавался при регистрации такие как =-->

```
    <?php
.
..
...
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://site/user/*ivan*/">
..
..
...
    blahblah($_BLAHBLAH["blahblah"], "www/home/site/user/*ivan*/".$_BLAHBLAH["blahblah"]);
...
..
.
    ?>
```

Полагаюсь на то, что профессионалы меня поняли, в ответе можете описать как и полный (толковый) вариант, так и пример, чтобы подтолкнуть меня на правильную идею решения данной задачи.

P.S. Не бывает нерешимых задач!

P.P.S. А также спешу вас проинформировать, что у меня появлялись идеи решения этой задачи, одна из которых являлась выгруз информации из базы посредством sql запросов, что сразу отпало, так как в этом нужно было бы дольше копаться .

(Я уже безуспешно применял свои идеи, и поэтому пришел к вам за советом.)

Спасибо всем за внимание.

**Обновление**

...вот мне и нужна та функция которая отвечает за редактирование содержимого файла как .htacces тк и index.php .

А функцию создания дефолтного файла в папку нового юзера я нашел- делается через FOPEN примерно так...

```
$document_root = $config['/www/site/user/default/']; //создать из папки

$file="$/www/site/user/ivan/$folder/index.php"; //создать тут (в нового юзера)

unlink($file); // Delete old file

if( !file_exists($file))

{

  $fp = fopen($file, "w"); // ("r" - Считывать "w" - Создавать "a" - добовлять к тексту), мы создаем файл

  fwrite($fp, "$items2");

  fclose($fp);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам **не нужно** создавать такие папки, исходя из описанной задачи. Почему:

1. сложно будет поменять разом всем пользователям их index.php и save.php, а сделать это вам обязательно захочется, причём очень скоро, и не один раз;
2. как я понимаю, вы собираетесь принимать файлы от пользователей, и хранить их в этих же папках — вас сломает любой школьник;

Кто виноват, что делать и как жить дальше

1. имена и данные пользователей хранить в БД;
2. все запросы глубже корневой папки обрабатывать единственным корневым index.php – это называется "front controller". Разберитесь, как для этого настроить ваш веб сервер. В итоге все запросы типа `site.ru/user/ivan/save` внутри будут переделаны в запрос `site.ru/index.php?user=ivan&action=save`;
3. примерно то же можно сделать с загруженными файлами: запретить исполнение скриптов в папках с этими файлами, и отдавать их , переписав запрос `site.ru/users/ivan/files/blablabla.zip` на `/files/uploads/ivan/blablabla.zip`.

Все описанные задачи с возможными подводными камнями решены в большинстве популярных фреймворков. Поэтому, возможно, стоит взять какой-нибудь из них, и не изобретать плохой велосипед?

Comment: ыыыыыыыыыыыыы

Comment: Спасибо. но то что вы описали мне - я и об этом подумывал (этим фронтКонтроллером я воспользуюсь по другому), но мне проще сделать так что бы другие пользователи авторизованные и не, заходили в директорию других пользователей (в открытую зону) и скачивали всё что им хочется , так же и на закрытых зонах будет естественно стоять .htacces - содержаший в себе логин/пасс тот что задавался при регистрации... 

(на этот счет у меня есть идеи)...

Comment: @ZET нет-нет, речь только про низкоуровневые отдельные моменты. Напр., зачем вам заново писать работу с БД, если можно взять готовый класс для работы с БД: `$user = DB::select( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?", array("ivan"));` и не писать коннект к базе, не проверять введённые юзером данные и быть уверенным, что вам не сделают sql-инъекцию, и не париться, что у вас установлено: mysql, mysqli, или что-то ещё.

Потом, захотите сделать что-то, а оно, раз – уже реализовано в вашем фреймворке, и вы в одну команду делаете себе REST контроллер и открываете API к вашему супер-пупер сервису.

Comment: Хмм.. Звучит соблазнительно, хорошо я рассмотрю и ваш вариант.

Спасибо! 8)

Answer (score 0):

Извините, может быть, конечно, это дело не моё, но, почитав и вашу предыдущую тему, и текущую, чего-то я понять не могу.

А не проще ли просто грузить файлы все в одну кучу, а в БД, например, писать имя файла, содержащего аватар там, и т.д. 
А дальше уже и подтягивать его как надо.

Comment: Да. само собой.как уже писал в вопросе я думал над этим вариантом но так как там нужно будет очень много копаться то думаю мне бы подошел скорее вариант с тегом FOPEN...

Answer (score 0):

Не понял, в чём у вас затруднения... Я бы вынес все изменяемые параметры в отдельный файл. Этот файл создавать динамически при регистрации, а остальные просто копировать из дефолтного каталога. Либо, как вариант, использовать принцип шаблона: берём заготовленный файл, ищем в нём все вхождения {{name}}(для примера) и заменяем на содержимое $name.

ЗЫ: Вы решили линукс на ПХП написать? : ))

Comment: Спсибо, нет,решил не линукс написать а (современный велосипед) сайт-хранитель файлов, где при регистрации у нового пользователя создастся своя директория со своей дефолтной конфигурации настроенная при регистрации (с настройками доступа к каталогу,и не много остальных изменений)

А о принципе шаблона можно еще чуть боле подробно в кодовом варианте?
Если правильно вас понял то речь идет о 

    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; URL=http://site/user/$username/">

?